# addsnapshotlistener triggers even though there is no update in Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, the `homepage` activity holds a sectioned `recyclerview`, in which the value is initiated by querying Firebase. The data retrieval and the `recyclerview` was working well at first.

Then, I tried to implement `addsnapshotlistener` to automatically update my activity without needing the user to refresh the page independently.

However, when I run my code, the `recyclerview` repeated the same sectioned `recyclerview` twice.

Here is the code for my activity:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    ///storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    UserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    MainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.MainContainer);
    SignoutButton = findViewById(R.id.SignOutbutton);

    checkUserType();

    SignoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            ///mAuth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(apiClient);
            Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    ///queries data from firebase
    initData();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.appointment);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.search:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Search.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.appointment:
                    return true;
                case R.id.profile:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    UpdateToken();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    sectionList.clear();
    apnmntList.clear();

    CollectionReference colref = db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
            .collection("Date");

    ///check for updates inside of the collections
    HPListener= colref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {

                ///query all the values again
                db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
                        .collection("Date").document(document.getId())
                        .collection("appointmentsID")
                        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        apnmntList = new ArrayList();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot querysnapshot: task.getResult()){

                            apnmtDetails details = new apnmtDetails(
                                    querysnapshot.getString("customer name"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("barberID"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("shop name"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("name"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("type"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("status"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("price"),
                                    querysnapshot.getString("time slot"));

                            apnmntList.add(details);
                            section = new Section(document.getString("date"),apnmntList);

                        }

                        ///notify recyclerview
                        sectionList.add(section);
                        mainRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    HPListener.remove();
}

private void checkUserType() {
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(UserId);
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (value.exists()) {
                userType = "Users";
            } else {
            userType = "Barbers";
            }
        }
    });

}

private void initData(){

    db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
            .collection("Date")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            ///getting the list of appointments and their details
                            db.collection("appointmentsColl").document(UserId)
                                    .collection("Date").document(document.getId())
                                    .collection("appointmentsID")
                                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    apnmntList = new ArrayList();
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot querysnapshot: task.getResult()){

                                        apnmtDetails details = new apnmtDetails(
                                                querysnapshot.getString("customer name"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("barberID"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("shop name"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("name"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("type"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("status"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("price"),
                                                querysnapshot.getString("time slot"));

                                        ///adding appointmnets into an arraylist
                                        apnmntList.add(details);

                                        ///saving the value of the section title and the appointments arraylist inside one object
                                        section = new Section(document.getString("date"),apnmntList);

                                    }

                                    ////initializing a new array list with the section's objects
                                    sectionList.add(section);

                                    ///initializes the main recyclerview
                                    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomePage.this);
                                    manager.setReverseLayout(true);
                                    manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                                    MainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
                                    MainRecyclerView.setAdapter(mainRecyclerAdapter);
                                }

                            });
                        }

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i("Check", e.toString() );
        }
    });

}

private void UpdateToken() {

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String refreshToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Token token= new Token(refreshToken);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);
}
```

Here is what my output looks like before and after implementing `addsnapshotlistener:`

### Before

[image: before]

### After

[image: after]

I tinkered with the `addsnapshotlistener` for a while because I was not sure whether it is the cause for the problem, so I tried to replace the method inside the `addsnapshotlistener` with:

```
finish();

startActivity(getIntent()
```

I thought this would work, but when I tried to run my code, the homepage started to refresh itself endlessly without stopping.

I tried to search for people with the same problem as my own, but the posts that I find stated that their `addsnapshotlistener` triggers correctly but return twice the instance of the data.

The method triggers itself when I open my activity, and it triggers itself even if there are no updates in Firebase.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this problem or maybe guide me to any link or post that can help solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your data retrieval was working well at first. Have you changed anything recently?

From reading your code, I cannot see where you are handling any errors you might encounter. A listener may fail due to a security setting change or an invalid query.

It would help if you implemented an error callback to help you better understand what has happened. For example, you can capture the error message as `e` and output the error.

```java
if (e != null) {
          System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
          return;
        }
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors):

```java
db.collection("cities")
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                          @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
          System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
          return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
          if (dc.getType() == Type.ADDED) {
            System.out.println("New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
          }
        }
      }
    });
```